# How to use Elasticsearch and Shield with Laravel 5?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, laravel-5

Elasticsearch packages existed for laravel 5 in git-hub but for securing elastic another package `shield` is existed. now i want to know how we can use that `shield` package with laravel elasticsearch packge, or is there any package in laravel that integrated with `shield` or no. any guide just for starting this.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to add more details, which ElasticSearch package you have used, and what did you try and got stuck.

Comment: @MinaYoussef I used this package `http://packalyst.com/packages/package/adobradi/laravel5-elastic` for elasticsearch but don't have any idea about how to integrate shield with.

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/elastic.php` add the username:password as below

```
<?php
return [
    'hosts' => [
        // 'localhost:9200',
        // 'user:pass@localhost:9200'
    ]
];
```

Comment: Can your describe more about this.

Comment: Did you publish your config after installing the elasticsearch package?